# Delete files after upload with WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

My script is very simple

```
// Setup session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp,
    HostName = conHostName,
    UserName = conUserName,
    Password = conPasswort,
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = conSshHostKeyFingerprint
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    TransferOptions transferOptions = new TransferOptions();
    transferOptions.TransferMode = TransferMode.Binary;

    TransferOperationResult transferResult;

    if(modus == "download")
    {
        transferResult = session.GetFiles(
            remoteDirectoryDownload, localDirectoryDownload, false, transferOptions);
    } 
    else
    {
        transferResult = session.PutFiles(
            localDirectoryUpload, remoteDirectoryUpload, false, transferOptions);
    }
    
    transferResult.Check();

    foreach (TransferEventArgs transfer in transferResult.Transfers)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Delete File: {0}", transfer.FileName);
            session.RemoveFiles(transfer.FileName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
        }
    }
}
```

When I do the download, then the files from the remote host would be transferred and deleted on the remote host. But when I make the upload from the local folder, then the uploads would work but the file on the local folder would not be deleted. I get no error.

I start this with my user. I am the owner of this files and I can delete them self manually.

Also when I set a breakpoint on `session.RemoveFiles`, then the correct file with the correct local path would be shown.

Maybe you have a idea for me where my fail is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Session.RemoveFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_removefiles) deletes *remote* files only. It cannot delete *local* files. For deleting *local* files, use the standard .NET [`File.Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete).

Though easier (and better) is to pass `true` to the `remove` (3rd) argument of  [`Session.GetFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles)/[`Session.PutFiles`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_putfiles).

It's better than your current code even for downloads, as it deletes all successfully downloaded files. While your current code won't delete any files, if only part of the files are downloaded successfully.

Also, you are using the default `TransferOptions`, so that code is redundant.

In the end, you can simplify your code to:

```
using (Session session = new Session())
{
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    if (modus == "download")
    {
        session.GetFiles(remoteDirectoryDownload, localDirectoryDownload, true).Check();
    } 
    else
    {
        session.PutFiles(localDirectoryUpload, remoteDirectoryUpload, true).Check();
    }
}
```